# @media query does not resize

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to make one part of the page responsive. But I cant get it working.
Only the media query with `1920px` works.

this is my code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (min-width: 1350px) {
        #designer-info {
    margin-right: -129px;
    }
}    
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1700px) {
        #designer-info{
        margin-right:-8%;
    }
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 2880px) and (min-width: 1920px) {
        #designer-info {
    margin-right: -430px;
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me. i cant find the solution.

Comment: `Only the media query with 1920px works` ... there are _two_ media queries which have this dimension, which one are you referring to?

Comment: Im sorry i was referring to the: media screen and media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1700px) {
        #designer-info{
        margin-right:-8%;
    }
}

Comment: @keescavia did you see my comment?

Answer (score 1):

Not working because you have in one query `min-width:1920px` and in another query `max-width:1920px`, so it will override.

---

don't need to use both `max-width` and `min-width`

either use mobile first approach using `min-width`

```css
@media (min-width: 1350px) {
  #designer-info {
    margin-right: -129px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  #designer-info {
    margin-right: -8%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #designer-info {
    margin-right: -430px;
  }
}
```

or non-mobile approach using `max-width`

```css
@media (max-width: 2880px) {
  #designer-info {
    margin-right: -430px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1920px) {
    #designer-info {
      margin-right: -8%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1440px) {
    #designer-info {
      margin-right: -129px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in `HTML` head section.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ...
 </head>
 <body>
   ...
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you know OP doesn't have it?

Comment: It will be possible when I think.

Answer (score 0):

maybe override there `(max-width: 1920px)` and `(min-width: 1920px)`

You should to use the different width in each media query.

Hope this can help you
Ex.

`(max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1700px)`

and

`(max-width: 1921px) and (min-width: 2880px)`